# ERROR: No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, boot, drivers, grub2

I've acer-pc which had at the beginning installed oem windows 8 or 8.1 x64. Later I wanted to install custom ubuntu. I checked oem/normal/x86/x64, other windows installations. I've installed os even on other hard drives that I thought it might be disc issue but it's not.

Now after x64 ubuntu installation it still show the `ERROR: No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed.` message which does not allow to use that pc in any way.

I've started ubuntu from usb (after oemubuntu/next/next installation) it shows:

```
sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST3250410AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32                 boot
 2      538MB   237GB  237GB   ext4
 3      237GB   250GB  12.8GB  linux-swap(v1)
```

About  `Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]`:

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/MokManager.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.05 20140113
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 2039876 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the  directory. 
                       The integrity check of the ADV area failed. No errors 
                       found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux/syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 249.9 GB, 249923032064 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30384 cylinders, total 488130922 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1   488,130,921   488,130,921  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048     1,050,623     1,048,576 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2       1,050,624   463,060,991   462,010,368 Data partition (Linux)
/dev/sda3     463,060,992   488,130,559    25,069,568 Swap partition (Linux)

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
```

... and END of this file:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda2/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=8168ed63-0e0e-4921-9480-b7c8fe1772e5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=E63F-01E0  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=21500b24-730b-4326-8f5f-e95c83ac17b0 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


=========================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

========================= sdb1/syslinux/syslinux.cfg: ==========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# D-I config version 2.0
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 50
ui gfxboot bootlogo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


================= sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux: ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


============== sdb1: Version of COM32(R) files used by Syslinux: ===============

 syslinux/chain.c32                 :  COM32R module (v4.xx)
 syslinux/gfxboot.c32               :  COM32R module (v4.xx)
 syslinux/vesamenu.c32              :  COM32R module (v4.xx)

========= Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive: =========

sdc 

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-CvknuXt4/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
/home/ubuntu/Downloads/bootinfoscript-061/bootinfoscript: line 1646: [: 2.73495e+09: integer expression expected
cat: /tmp/BootInfo-CvknuXt4/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/BootInfo-CvknuXt4/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
  No volume groups found
```

Regards

Comment: With /dev/sda2 /mnt it mounts the partition but after restart it still show's this err "ERROR: No boot disk ..."

Comment: What can I do to get an answer for this issue ? :)

Comment: What do you mean by "custom ubuntu"? What did you change? Where did you install the GRUB boot loader?

Comment: Looks like your bios is being stupid.  You didn't disable EFI mode did you?  What does `sudo efibootmgr -v` show?  You might try using `fdisk` to mark a partition as active... some very stupid bios insist there be an active partition or they give an error like that.

Comment: I mean while installing Ubuntu just left all for next->next so every configuration detail left for system.

Comment: Any idea what might cause that ?